# Keep animation page curl effect in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I'm making an simple PDF reader program myself.

It work well in simulators and iphone, ipad. But I had a problem.

Page curl work well but if you stop the touch, page flip immediately.

Since touch event end I want page change animation during 0.5 second.

Here's My code.  Thanks.

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
        filter = [[CAFilter filterWithType:kCAFilterPageCurl] retain];
        [filter setDefaults];

        //lastPos save the touchesBegan location;
        //currentPos is a current location; 
        CGFloat _angleRad = angleBetweenCGPoints(currentPos, lastPos);
        CGPoint fingerVector = vectorBetweenPoints(currentPos, lastPos);
        float distanceVecX = -fingerVector.x/windowbounds.size.width;

        if(m_bCurlprev)
        {
                [filter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:_angleRad] forKey:@"inputAngle"];
                pdfView.layer.filters = [NSArray arrayWithObject:filter];
                [filter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:distanceVecX] forKey:@"inputTime"];
        }
        else{
                if(inputTime == 0) 
                        [self addSubview:forwardPDFView];
                [filter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:_angleRad] forKey:@"inputAngle"];
                forwardPDFView.layer.filters = [NSArray arrayWithObject:filter];
                [filter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:distanceVecX] forKey:@"inputTime"];
        }
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
        if ([[filter valueForKey:@"inputTime"] floatValue] >= 0.5)
    {   
        [filter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0] forKey:@"inputTime"];
        if(m_bCurlprev==NO)
        {
            pdfView.layer.filters = nil;
            [self nextView];
        }
        else
        {
            pdfView.layer.filters = nil;
            [forwardPDFView removeFromSuperview];
            m_bCurlprev = NO;
        }
    }
    else if ([[filter valueForKey:@"inputTime"] floatValue] != 0.0 || m_bCurlprev==YES)
    {   
        [filter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0] forKey:@"inputTime"];
        if(m_bCurlprev==YES)
        {
            pdfView.layer.filters = nil;
            [forwardPDFView removeFromSuperview];
            [self prevView];
            m_bCurlprev = NO;
        }
        else
        {
            pdfView.layer.filters = nil;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: As I commented on your other question, CAFilter is private API as of iOS 4.x (and I believe still with 5.0), so you should not use this in an application you intend to submit to the App Store.  Odds are, it will be rejected by Apple.

Comment: can you share your project demo code with me?